# How to dynamically merge columns of XLSX downloads from an R Shiny app using the xlsx package?

Tags: r, shiny, xlsx

I'm trying to dynamically merge columns of XLSX downloads from an R Shiny app using the xlsx package. I can currently merge columns of an XLSX document created from a static dataframe as demonstrated in the following minimal example:

```
library(xlsx)

# Creating dataframe.
df <- data.frame(c("Title", 1, "one"),
                 c("", 2, "two"),
                 c("", 3, "three"))

# Creating a workbook using the XLSX package.
wb <- xlsx::createWorkbook(type = "xlsx")

# Creating a sheet inside the workbook.
sheet <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, sheetName = "Sheet0")

# Adding the full dataset into the sheet.
xlsx::addDataFrame(df, sheet, startRow = 1, startCol = 1, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

# Merging first three columns.
addMergedRegion(sheet, 1, 1, 1, 3)

# Saving the workbook.
xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, "df.xlsx")
```

I've implemented this example's logic in the following R Shiny app:

```
# ui.R

fluidPage(
  h1("Download XLSX"),
  downloadButton("download.button", label = "Download")
)

# server.R

library(xlsx)

function(input, output) {

  # Creating dataframe.
  df <- data.frame(c("Title", 1, "one"),
                   c("", 2, "two"),
                   c("", 3, "three"))

  # Handling download.
  # Creating XLSX file for download.
  output$download.button <- downloadHandler(
    filename <- paste0("df.xlsx"),
    content <- function(file) {
      # Creating a workbook using the XLSX package.
      wb <- xlsx::createWorkbook(type = "xlsx")

      # Creating a sheet inside the workbook.
      sheet <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, sheetName = "Sheet0")

      # Adding the full dataset into the sheet.
      xlsx::addDataFrame(df, sheet, startRow = 1, startCol = 1, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

      # Merging first three columns.
      addMergedRegion(sheet, 1, 1, 1, 3)

      # Saving the workbook.
      xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, file)
    }
  )

}
```

In the above example, `addMergedRegion(sheet, 1, 1, 1, 3)` merges the first three columns of the first row together as one. I'd like to be able to do this dynamically rather than through hard coding because I will be working with dataframes of various sizes. As input I want to use a list of row indices, column indices, and column spans. These would be all of the values I need to fill the `addMergedRegion()` function, however, I'm unsure of how to dynamically generate the functions needed to merge columns. As one example of this challenge, I made this second app:

```
# ui.R

fluidPage(
  h1("Download XLSX"),
  numericInput("numeric.input", "Select Number of Tables:", 1, min = 1),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
  downloadButton("download.button", label = "Download")
)

# server.R

library(DT)
library(xlsx)

function(input, output) {

  # Creating dataframe.
  df <- data.frame(c("Title", 1, "one"),
                   c("", 2, "two"),
                   c("", 3, "three"))

  # Creating reactive dataframe.
  values <- reactiveValues(
    df = df
  )

  # Expanding dataframe based on user input.
  observeEvent(input$numeric.input, {
    values$df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), input$numeric.input), ]
  })

  # Rendering data table of dataframe.
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(values$df,
                  selection = "none",
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  options = list(dom = "t",
                                 ordering = FALSE,
                                 pageLength = nrow(values$df)))
  })

  # Handling download.
  # Creating XLSX file for download.
  output$download.button <- downloadHandler(
    filename <- paste0("df.xlsx"),
    content <- function(file) {
      # Creating a workbook using the XLSX package.
      wb <- xlsx::createWorkbook(type = "xlsx")

      # Creating a sheet inside the workbook.
      sheet <- xlsx::createSheet(wb, sheetName = "Sheet0")

      # Adding the full dataset into the sheet.
      xlsx::addDataFrame(values$df, sheet, startRow = 1, startCol = 1, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

      # Saving the workbook.
      xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, file)
    }
  )

}
```

This app extends the dataframe rows based on user input. How can I give each cell containing the string "Title" a column span of 3 in a dynamic case such as this?

Comment: I think you will get more answers if you make your code minimal. See [mcve]. The Shiny stuff is really not relevant here, and I don't much want to start a full-fledged Shiny app so as to help you debug!

Comment: Good suggestion, I've added a minimal example to the top of the above question. Do you think that I should remake the question outside of the R Shiny section?

Comment: Yes. Your basic question is pure `openxlsx`, right? Give cells a colspan of 3 if they contain the string "Title". Everything else is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't use `xlsx` due to java woes, but I think all you need is:

```
indices <- which(df=="Title", arr.ind=TRUE)
```

This will give you a n x 2 matrix of row and column indices which you can then use in `addMergedRegion`:

```
apply(indices, 1, function (x) {
  xlsx::addMergedRegion(sheet, x[1], x[1], x[2], x[2] + 2)
})
```

Life will be slightly more complex if you want cells that *contain* "Title" rather than cells that *equal* "Title":

```
x <- matrix(NA, nrow(df), ncol(df))
x[] <- grepl("Title", unlist(df))
indices <- which(x, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

... and proceed as before.